# What does it means user-declared for Implicitly-declared move assignment operator?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, move-assignment-operator

The statement

> **Implicitly-declared move assignment operator**
>
> If no user-defined move assignment operators are provided for a class
>   type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> there are no user-declared copy constructors;
>    *there are no user-declared move constructors;*
>    *there are no user-declared copy assignment operators;*
>    there are no user-declared destructors;

with **user-declared** copy assigment operator does it means only

> class_name & class_name :: operator= ( class_name && )

or **any** `operator=()` defined?

Example:

```
class Bar
{
public:
   Bar() = default;
   SomeClass some;
};

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() = default;

   Foo& operator=(Bar&& bar) : some(std::move(bar.some))
   {
   }

   SomeClass some;
};
```

Does that match the condition for an implitely-declared move assigmnent operator?

The same goes for the implicitly-declared move constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it says "user-declared **copy** assignment operators" (emphasis mine). Not every assignment operator is a copy assignment operator.

For class `X`, a *copy* assignment operator is defined as `operator=` which takes a parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&`, or `const volatile X&`. So your `Foo::operator=(Bar&&)` is not a *copy* assignment operator, and thus does not affect the implicit declaration of a move (or copy) assignment operator.

Comment: So it has to match the `class_name & class_name :: operator= ( class_name && )` syntax. I was not totally sure about that, thanks.

Comment: @Moia Well, not exactly. First off, that would be a *move* assignment operator, not a *copy* one. Second, the return type does not affect whether something is a copy/move assignment operator; only the parameter type does.